# How to set image to button on widget?

Tags: android

I need to assign an image to button using package name of the app.The button is on the remote view,i.e, the button is on the widget.Please help me with this.

```
Button myButton = (Button)a.findViewById(R.id.button);
                 PackageManager packageManager=a.getPackageManager();
                 ApplicationInfo app = a.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.whatsapp", 0);
                    Drawable icon;
                    icon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(app);
                    if(icon!=null)
               {
                    myButton.setBackgroundResorce(icon);

            } 
        }
                catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(a.getApplicationContext(), "error in getting icon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                         toast.show();
                         e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Above is the code that i have written to get the image of the app using package name and assign to button.Now this is working fine on plain xml.I need to do the same to the button which is on widget.

Comment: mean background image??? button.setBackgroundResource(resId);  
or button indicate specific image? so store image name or id in button tag for ex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(icon);
```

setBackgroundResorce(); use for Resource in your package

---

edit 1 :

```
public void setIcontoButton(Button targetButton, Drawable icon)
{
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        targetButton.setBackgroundDrawable(icon)
    } else {
        targetButton.setBackground(icon);
    }

}
```

and change code to :

```
setIcontoButton(myButton,icon);
```

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable() is deprecated

Comment: @Sharath what is your api version ?

Comment: @Sharath i have edit my answer, setBackgroundDrawable is deprecated but it still works

Comment: my button is on remoteview Leon.How assign this to remoteview

Comment: @Sharath can you use imageButton instead button?

Comment: ooh nice idea.I will try and let u know